# Add CollectionView as Table View Header

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I want to show banner like this:

[image]

My approach is adding a `CollectionView` as a `TableViewHeader`

My code:

```
extension HomeViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func configureHeaderView() {

        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)

        let headerView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: headerHeight), collectionViewLayout: layout)
        headerView.backgroundColor = .blue
        headerView.isPagingEnabled = true
        headerView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        headerView.dataSource = self
        headerView.delegate = self
        headerView.register(BannerCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: BannerCollectionViewCell.reuseIdentifier)
        headerView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false

        tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView
    }

    // MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: BannerCollectionViewCell.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! BannerCollectionViewCell
        return cell
    }

    // MARK: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: headerHeight)
    }
}
```

My `BannerCollectionViewCell` has a default image.

```
class BannerCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var bannerImageView: UIImageView!

}
```

[image]

But I don't see that image on my header. It just show an empty header.

Comment: Have you tried using the delegate method `viewForHeaderInSection`?

Comment: Not yet, I have set `tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView`, are they equivalent to each other?

Comment: in `cellForItemAt indexPath` , you have to set image. like `cell.imageView.image = "abc.png"`

Comment: Not exactly, but if you only have 1 section both works.

Comment: #Ben Ong, I have only 1 section, #the_dahiya_boy, I have set default image.

Comment: Does your `BannerCollectionViewCell` init with any visible information? You might be seeing empty view because everything is white.

Comment: `BannerCollectionViewCell` has only 1 visible default image, but it doesn't show in my header

Comment: @Khuong From where you adding the image, I still didn't getting you. :(

Comment: @the_dahiya_boy I set it in a xib file

Comment: @Khuong and what `BannerCollectionViewCell.reuseIdentifier` returns, check. And even use `Debug View Hirarchy` to check is really collectioview is present., if yes at what condition.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you use the **NIB**, so you should use `func register(UINib?, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: String)` instead of `func register(AnyClass?, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: String)`

Comment: Post answer only if you have any answer regarding to question otherwise write in comment.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Thanks for your all helps :)

Comment: @zhongwuzw Thanks I'm having issues with Autolayout . Could you help me?

Answer (score -3):

Maybe you're looking for an image pager like [KIImagePager](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/kiimagepager) on the top instead of a collection view. You can also create the same using inbuilt `PageViewController`.

You can add a `TableView` separately below this.

Comment: He is using `UIcollectionview` by disabling verticle move, not `PageController`